# Meaning of a second occurrence of "on which" in a single sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar

Could someone teach me what the following sentence means? I don't understand about the second instance of "on which"; is that "on the platform" or "on the trade surplus"?

> "A recent Chinese white paper on China's membership of the WTO will do nothing to alter the beliefs of those who see the WTO as the platform on which China has built the trade surplus on which the Trump administration is now waging trade war."

Many thanks for your help.

Hoo

Answer (score 1):

The first "on which" refers to the WTO as a platform.  The second refers to China's trade surplus.  The overall phrase means that China has built a trade surplus using the WTO as a platform, and that Trump is currently waging war on that trade surplus.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! It is very helpful to understand the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. It is incredibly poorly worded.
To be honest I think it is neither, but it is inherently more indicative of the platform despite the grammar more pointing at the surplus.